# How to build a list by successively applying a function while varying only one parameter?

Tags: functional-style

I have to create a list by varying one parameter of a function. For now, I resort on that solution:

```
Map[Function[m, f[arg1, arg2, m, arg4]], Range[-3,3]]
```

> ```
> { f[arg1,arg2,-3,arg4],
>   f[arg1,arg2,-2,arg4],
>   f[arg1,arg2,-1,arg4],
>   f[arg1,arg2,0,arg4],
>   f[arg1,arg2,1,arg4],
>   f[arg1,arg2,2,arg4],
>   f[arg1,arg2,3,arg4] }
> ```

It works as expected. But it requires creating a dummy pure function just for the sake of mapping a parameter to a Range. So, I wonder if there wouldn't exist a simpler and/or more elegant solution?

Obviously, there is the [`For`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) loop, but I searched through the documentation and didn't find a "functional style" equivalent of that construct.

Comment: `Thread[f[arg1,arg2,Range[-3,3],arg4]`

Comment: The short form for what you wrote is `f[arg1, arg2, #, arg4] & /@ Range[-3, 3]`

Comment: Also, `SetAttributes[f, Listable]; 

f[arg1, arg2, Range[-3, 3], arg4]`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @ciao Wouldn't a `Thread`-based solution break if one of the argN is a list?

Comment: @ciao `With[{arg1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}}, Thread[f[arg1,arg2,Range[-3,3],arg4]]]` doesn't work as I expect since `arg1` is not passed as a list to `f`.

Comment: Thanks @Bob That may be a solution. This is shorter, and possibly looks more like a Mathematica idiom. However, under the hood, this is exactly the same thing. Should I assume there is no "better" way? Maybe I am just chasing the white rabbit ;)

Comment: What is "better" is mostly a matter of taste or what is easier for you to remember unless efficiency is important; in which case, timing tests would tell you which of the methods is more efficient.

Comment: Yes, @Bob, you're right. If you say this is how it's done with Mathematica, I will stick with that solution or the compact form, as you suggested.

Comment: You can specify which argument is being threaded by providing a third argument to `Thread`: `Thread[f[arg1, arg2, Range[-3, 3], arg4], List, {3}]`.

Comment: Excellent @asterix314! I think this could be useful for other users. Would you consider posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread` accepts 2 more arguments in addition to the target expression: a head specification (usually `List`) and a *sequence specification* to narrow down the scope of arguments to be threaded. So for example:

```
With[{arg1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}}, Thread[f[arg1, arg2, Range[-3, 3], arg4], List, {3}]]
```

would only expland on the third argument and leave the rest intact.